# Приоритет операторов в Python

Tags: python, операторы

В Python возможно одновременное присваивание значений нескольким переменным:

```python
a, b = 1, 2
a, b = b, a
```

И в то же время при объявлении функции допускается указание дефолтных значений:

```python
def myfunc(a, b=0):
    return a+b
```

Получается, что приоритет оператора "запятая" в первом случае выше, чем у оператора присваивания, а во втором случае оператор присваивания имеет более высокий приоритет? Как в действительности считается приоритет операторов в этом случае, и по возможности подскажите, как (предположительно) в Python реализуется такой переменный приоритет?

PS. Зачем мне это нужно: Я разрабатываю язык макросов для приложения (для этого, чтобы не изобретать велосипед, беру примеры в других языках), и хочу внедрить массовое присваивание и параметры по умолчанию. Для этого мне нужно определиться с приоритетом операторов, и как-то решить эту проблему: не хотелось бы хардкодить, задавать переменный приоритет для запятой, проверяя, в скобках ли она или нет, что усложнит код парсера и сделает его менее удобным для дальнейшего расширения.

Comment: Так тут дело не в том, что они в скобках, а в том, что во втором случае речь про описание аргументов функции, там нельзя делать вычисления и совсем всё по-другому обрабатывается, чем когда речь о вычислении выражений. Так что запятые, скобки и знак равенства в этих случаях совершенно по-разному трактуются.

Comment: @CrazyElf, по идее да, т.е. это мы так трактуем своим мозгом, но когда парсер кушает токекы, полученные из лексера, он разве не ориентируется на приоритет?

Comment: Я думаю он ориентируется на то, что ранее был def и значит это описание функции, а не просто выражение само по себе

Comment: @PavelSumarokov, почему вы продолжаете спрашивать именно про приоритет? Я не зря написал, что это вообще неверная постановка задачи для Python. Нет тут приоритета, "что был def" - это тоже отработка синтаксиса.  И это же не С, это там запятая - оператор. Или вы переопределили это слово как-то?

Comment: @Сергей, но ведь когда парсер принимает токены, он как-то должен понимать, в каком порядке засовывать их в AST-дерево, не так ли?

Comment: @PavelSumarokov, понял, от приоритета операторов вы перешли к приоритету для парсера. Тогда ответ всё тот же, что я уже дал ниже - "изначально интерпретатор проводит синтаксически определённые изменения". Но если этого ответа вам не достаточно, то вернусь чуть позже с дополнением.

Comment: @Сергей, т.е. эти синтаксические изменения должны быть между лексером и парсером? И эти изменения не должны удлинять время интерпретации?

Comment: @PavelSumarokov, согласно документации на вход парсера поступает поток токенов из лексера - первая же строка в <https://python.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/lexical_analysis.html#index-0>. Токены на выходе лексера я для наглядности включил в ответ для a,b=b,a, там явно нет ещё нужного преобразования. 
Слово "интерпретатор" я использовал для простоты, на самом деле на этом этапе работает ещё компилятор Python. Удлинения времени быть особого не должно на мой взгляд. Обновлю ответ немного.

Comment: @Сергей, если нетрудно, посоветуйте какую-нибудь библиотеку построения AST-дерева из кода на Python. Глядя на это дерево мне всё станет понятно. Заранее спасибо)

Comment: @PavelSumarokov, добавил в ответ ещё полезной информации. Для дерева - самим Python и пользуйтесь. Если устроит - принимайте ответ:-) (на всякий случай: я Python меньше месяца изучаю, так что кто-то может и поточнее дать ответ. Но учтите, что тема эта не очень популярная, большого количества гуру не найдете, полагаю.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Запятая не является оператором в Python (т.е. неверно поставлен вопрос изначально - не идёт речи о приоритете операторов). Она - просто синтаксический разделитель в операции присваивания. Иными словами, компилятор Python преобразует согласно синтаксису языка выражение

```
    a, b = 1, 2
```

в (см.ниже в комментарии полезное исправление от @CrazyElf !)

```
      a=1
      b=2
```

Аналогично с

```
    a, b = b, a
```

Это просто сокращённая запись:

```
    temp = a
    a = b
    b = temp
```

Полагаю, правильно говорить, что изначально компилятор проводит синтаксически определённые изменения, и только после этого переходит к вопросу приоритетов.

Уточню, что согласно документации* на вход парсера подаётся поток токенов, так что преобразования эти должны проводится им. Сам же поток токенов рассматриваемое преобразование не содержит. Для наглядности пример с результатом токенизации для

```
    a, b = 1, 2
```

приведён ниже.

```
TokenInfo(type=63 (ENCODING), string='utf-8', start=(0, 0), end=(0, 0), line='')
TokenInfo(type=1 (NAME), string='a', start=(1, 0), end=(1, 1), line='a,b=1,2\r\n')
TokenInfo(type=54 (OP), string=',', start=(1, 1), end=(1, 2), line='a,b=1,2\r\n')
TokenInfo(type=1 (NAME), string='b', start=(1, 2), end=(1, 3), line='a,b=1,2\r\n')
TokenInfo(type=54 (OP), string='=', start=(1, 3), end=(1, 4), line='a,b=1,2\r\n')
TokenInfo(type=2 (NUMBER), string='1', start=(1, 4), end=(1, 5), line='a,b=1,2\r\n')
TokenInfo(type=54 (OP), string=',', start=(1, 5), end=(1, 6), line='a,b=1,2\r\n')
TokenInfo(type=2 (NUMBER), string='2', start=(1, 6), end=(1, 7), line='a,b=1,2\r\n')
TokenInfo(type=4 (NEWLINE), string='\r\n', start=(1, 7), end=(1, 9), line='a,b=1,2\r\n')
TokenInfo(type=0 (ENDMARKER), string='', start=(2, 0), end=(2, 0), line='')
```

Если же интересует непосредственно построение AST-дерева, то удобно воспользоваться стандартным модулем ast. Результат для нашего примера (можем видеть, что @CrazyElf был совершенно прав по поводу кортежей):

```
    Module(body=[Assign(targets=[Tuple(elts=[Name(id='a', ctx=Store()), Name(id='b', ctx=Store())], ctx=Store())], value=Tuple(elts=[Constant(value=1), Constant(value=2)], ctx=Load()))], type_ignores=[])
```

Вот интересная ссылка по поводу работы с AST и байт-кодом: https://habr.com/ru/company/piter/blog/493424/

А вот и код для токенизации и построения ast-дерева:

```
import ast
import tokenize
print("Токены:")
with open ('temp.py', 'rb') as f:   #файл содержит строку a,b=1,2
    for token in tokenize.tokenize(f.readline):
        print(token)
my_tree=ast.parse('a,b=1,2',)
print('\nAST-дерево:\n', ast.dump(my_tree))
```

*первая строка в https://python.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/lexical_analysis.html#index-0

Comment: А если ещё точнее, то в данном случае запятая образует кортеж `a, b` -> `(a, b)`, а дальше мы видим распаковку правого кортежа `(1, 2)` в левый кортеж `(a, b)`.

Comment: Спасибо большое за исправление! Не помнил этой тонкости. На всякий случай для @Pavel Sumarokov: Смысл моего ответа относительно вопроса не изменился.

Answer (score 1):

Я принял решение, в своём языке макросов, для массового присвоения значений переменным использовать "=":

```
a, b, c = 1, 2, 3;
```

А для значения параметра по умолчанию - паскалевский оператор ":=", присвоив ему высший приоритет:

```
myfunc = a, b:=0 => a + b;
```

Несмотря на то, что я сам отвечаю, правильный ответ я ставлю пользователю Сергей, как более полный, информативный и практически полезный.